# Mulitple data points at single point of time highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The scenario is represented in the fiddle below. I am using a column chart to represent the data. When there is multiple data only the highest is being displayed in the graph. I am expecting it to stack.

http://jsfiddle.net/7pccz1j4/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minTickInterval: 1
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'series1',
        data: [
            [1418075700000, 2],
            [1418076000000, 2],
            [1418076300000, 2],
            [1418076600000, 2],
            [1418076900000, 2],
            [1418077200000, 2],
            [1418077500000, 2],
            [1418077800000, 2],
            [1418078100000, 2],
            [1418078100000, 3],
            [1418078400000, 2],
            [1418078700000, 2],
            [1418079000000, 2]
        ]
    }]
  });
});
```

The same scenario with a line chart is this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/RKVgx/253/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [stacking](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.stacking) option like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/7pccz1j4/2/

```
plotOptions:{
        series:{
            stacking:'normal'
        }
},
```

Comment: Thank you.The stacking the works without explicitly setting if we specify the categories.